# How can I convert my json file into xlsx using Python?

Tags: python, json, api

I just started in Python.
The goal is to scrape air quality data every hour from an api for the same city.

I scraped the json data and I would like to convert my json file into an xlsx file with a row for each hour, but I am struggling with the for loop, I do not know how to get each observation and put it in the file in the right way.

This is the json file I want to convert :

```
    {
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
        "aqi": 45,
        "idx": 5722,
        "attributions": [
            {
                "url": "http://www.airparif.asso.fr/",
                "name": "AirParif - Association de surveillance de la qualit\u00e9 de l'air en \u00cele-de-France",
                "logo": "Paris-Air-Parif.png"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://waqi.info/",
                "name": "World Air Quality Index Project"
            }
        ],
        "city": {
            "geo": [
                48.856614,
                2.3522219
            ],
            "name": "Paris",
            "url": "https://aqicn.org/city/paris"
        },
        "dominentpol": "pm10",
        "iaqi": {
            "co": {
                "v": 0.1
            },
            "h": {
                "v": 38
            },
            "no2": {
                "v": 11.9
            },
            "o3": {
                "v": 41.8
            },
            "p": {
                "v": 1021.3
            },
            "pm10": {
                "v": 45
            },
            "pm25": {
                "v": 93
            },
            "so2": {
                "v": 1.4
            },
            "t": {
                "v": 23.8
            },
            "w": {
                "v": 0.4
            }
        },
        "time": {
            "s": "2020-04-10 14:00:00",
            "tz": "+02:00",
            "v": 1586527200
        },
        "debug": {
            "sync": "2020-04-10T21:53:16+09:00"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code :

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

request = requests.get("https://api.waqi.info/feed/paris/?token=?")
request_text = request.text

data = json.loads(request_text)

#print(type(data["status"]))
data_serialized = json.dump(data, open('data.json',"w"),indent = 4)

#for observation in data['data']:
    print(observation)
```

I think I am going to have to do multiple for loops in other for loops but I am not sure.

I would appreciate some help.
Thank you.

Comment: The JSON structure looks like it only contains one single observation (one timestamp); are you processing a structure like this for every row?

Comment: @ChristophBurschka I would like to get this data every hour, so one row for each timestamp ( I only have one at the time). and I would like to append new observation each hour into my xls. I hope that makes sense

Comment: BTW, you can simply do `data = request.json()`.